# How can I programmatically open/close notifications in Android?

Tags: android, android-notification-bar

I've searched everywhere, but can't find anything in the SDK or on Google on how to do this. I know it's possible because all the custom launchers are able to do it via a button press (LauncherPro, ADW, etc).

Thanks.

Comment: Does getSystemService("statusbar") return an object?

Comment: yes it does. But I can't map it to StatusBarManager because it's not a part of the public API. So, right now I just have it as type "Object". What can I do to it to make it useable?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can programmatically *close* the notification drawer by broadcasting an [`ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS) intent.

This causes "temporary system dialogs" to be dismissed. From the documentation:

> Some examples of temporary system dialogs are the notification window-shade and the recent tasks dialog.

This doesn't require any permissions, and has apparently been available since Android 1.0.

The following code works for me on a Nexus 4 running Android 5.0:

```java
Intent closeIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
context.sendBroadcast(closeIntent);
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The solution in the accepted answer didn't work for me.

Comment: Via `adb`: `adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS`

Comment: What about opening the notification drawer?

Comment: This is deprecated and doesn't work in Android 12

Comment: Sadly not usable in Android 12 anymore: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-all

Comment: anyone knows how to do that in Android 12 or higher (the documation it's not clear too much)

Answer (score 27):

The [answer from Ashwin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11323406/194894) works for Android versions below 4.2.2 (i.e. below version 17).  In 4.2.2, the "expand" method was changed to "expandNotificationsPanel".  If you don't use that method name for 4.2.2 and above, you will get a Null Pointer Exception.  So the code should be:

```
Object sbservice = getSystemService( "statusbar" );
Class<?> statusbarManager = Class.forName( "android.app.StatusBarManager" );
Method showsb;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
    showsb = statusbarManager.getMethod("expandNotificationsPanel");
}
else {
    showsb = statusbarManager.getMethod("expand");
}
showsb.invoke( sbservice );
```

And appropriate permission should be added to `AndroidManifest`.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR" />
```

Obviously, this is not part of the published API, so this is not guaranteed to work in the future and many people would advise against doing this.

Comment: Oh, and also in version 4.2.2, you can use the method "expandSettingsPanel" to directly display the new settings panel with the toggles that was made available starting in version 4.2.2.

Comment: I get InvocationTargetException

Comment: I had to add the permission to the testing project as well

Comment: I had to invoke collapsePanels on Android 4.3. Here's the source code: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/android-4.2.2_r1/services/java/com/android/server/StatusBarManagerService.java

Comment: You must add the following permission to run this code

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR" />

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on Samsung devices with Lollipop or higher. Am I wrong ?

Comment: @guy.gc On Samsung Lollipop, I'm getting java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) ... Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: get/set setting for user asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL... anyone has any workaround methods?

Comment: @kevinze: I am getting same error as your error. Do you solve it?

Answer (score 15):

Yes you can add this code to wherever you want it to execute

```
Object sbservice = getSystemService( "statusbar" );
Class<?> statusbarManager = Class.forName( "android.app.StatusBarManager" );
Method showsb = statusbarManager.getMethod( "expand" );
showsb.invoke( sbservice );
```

And add this permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR" />
```

Comment: Is there any way to make the transition faster?

Answer (score 4):

> How can I programmatically open/close notifications in Android?

What you want cannot be done using the Android SDK.

> I know it's possible because all the cuustome launchers are able to do it via a button press (LauncherPro, ADW, etc).

All of the "custom launchers" are bypassing the SDK, using a variation on the technique that @Yoni Samlan proposed in another answer to your question. Things that are not part of the SDK can be removed by device manufacturers, replaced by the core Android team in future releases, etc.

I would argue that what you want *should* be possible via the SDK; otherwise, it really limits alternative home screen implementations. However, what you and I want does not count for all that much.

Comment: OK, is there any "hacky" way to get the notifications to close? For example are there any flags I can set when launching an intent that would force the notification bar to get closed? Or anything else like that?

Comment: @user496854: Not that I am aware of.

Comment: @com, is there still no way to do this?

Comment: @whoabackoff: There is still nothing in the Android SDK for this.

Answer (score 4):

Sadly there's still no official API (requested [**here**](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/243338887), please consider starring), but for now, you can use this code, which I've generalized from all of the answers I've found :

```
// based on https://gist.github.com/XinyueZ/7bad2c02be425b350b7f 
// requires permission: "android.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR"
@SuppressLint("WrongConstant", "PrivateApi")
fun setExpandNotificationDrawer(context: Context, expand: Boolean) {
    try {
        val statusBarService = context.getSystemService("statusbar")
        val methodName =
                if (expand)
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) "expandNotificationsPanel" else "expand"
                else
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) "collapsePanels" else "collapse"
        val statusBarManager: Class<*> = Class.forName("android.app.StatusBarManager")
        val method: Method = statusBarManager.getMethod(methodName)
        method.invoke(statusBarService)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

EDIT: also adb command, which might be an alternative workaround (taken from [**here**](https://www.androidbugfix.com/2022/04/how-to-expandcollapse-status-bar.html)) :

collapse:

```
adb shell service call statusbar 2
```

expand:

```
adb shell service call statusbar 1
```

Answer (score 2):

[Christopher Orr's answer works great for closing the notification drawer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31735939/2898715).

You can use [AccessibilityServices](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService) to programmatically show the notifications or quick settings by calling:

- [`performGlobalAction`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html#performGlobalAction(int))`(`[`GLOBAL_ACTION_NOTIFICATIONS`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html#GLOBAL_ACTION_NOTIFICATIONS)`)`
- [`performGlobalAction`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html#performGlobalAction(int))`(`[`GLOBAL_ACTION_QUICK_SETTINGS`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html#GLOBAL_ACTION_QUICK_SETTINGS)`)`

Answer (score -3):

Here's the showNotifications method from Android's `Launcher`:

```
private void showNotifications() {
    final StatusBarManager statusBar = (StatusBarManager) getSystemService(STATUS_BAR_SERVICE);
    if (statusBar != null) {
        statusBar.expand();
    }
}
```

(which, as Robby indicated, is the "statusbar" system service).

Comment: This is not part of the Android SDK.

Comment: this doesn't work because there is no StatusBarManager  class in the public API

Comment: Yup. CommonsWare is right; I was just poking through the source code and not the related SDKs, sorry.

Comment: This is likely dead now, but Fede's UberMusic does just this! There are actually two permissions STATUS_BAR and EXPAND_STATUS_BAR that might be of use.