# How to Drop down status bar programmatically android

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I programmatically open/close notifications in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029354/how-can-i-programmatically-open-close-notifications-in-android)

I need a code that will drop down the status bar in android programmatically. Is there any way to drop it down ?

Comment: You can start by searching SO...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029354/how-can-i-programmatically-open-close-notifications-in-android

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this code anywhere.

```
Object sbservice = getSystemService( "statusbar" );
Class<?> statusbarManager = Class.forName( "android.app.StatusBarManager" );
Method expandMethod;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
            expandMethod = statusBarManager.getMethod("expandNotificationsPanel");
        } else {
            expandMethod = statusBarManager.getMethod("expand");
        }
expandMethod .invoke( sbservice );
```

Or to make it more short use this :

```
StatusBarManager statusBar = (StatusBarManager) getSystemService(STATUS_BAR_SERVICE);
statusBar.expand();
```

Permission is required in manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR" />
```

Comment: In 4.3 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR" /> is allowed only for system apps, so you can't do this.

Comment: "statusbar" is no longer a Context constant.