# How do I get a semi-transparent status bar?

Tags: android

I have managed to get a fully transparent status bar but I would like a semi-transparent one instead. Below is the code I added to achieve a fully transparent status bar.

In my styles.xml I added the following:

```
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
```

In my activity.xml:

```
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

In the onCreate of my activity.java:

```
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
```

This is what I would like to achieve:
[image: Semi-Transparent Status Bar]

Comment: Try full screen `getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);`

Comment: This works but the status bar isn't visible at first - I have to pull it down. Can I get it to permanent stay there?

Comment: I guess it's Android's immutable behavior. When you're asking for FULLSCREEN, they'll hide the status bar for normal causes.

Comment: Well, I found a reflection hack: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14320900/8572503

.However, it might not be your case - still try.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work either. I'm going to stick with your first suggestion.

Comment: I've written an answer, you can make that one as accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be multiple possible solutions for your problem :

**1.** Switch to fullscreen window

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

**2.** The XML way

```
<style name="AppTheme.MainActivity" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#ebebeb</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

create new color inside colors.xml

`<color name="blackT">#88000000</color>`

then inside style.xml change primary dark color

`<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/blackT</item>`

Comment: No luck with this. Still the same outcome.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22192691/9420472  you can check this post.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some option that you can implement on your code,

**Option 1:**
On your xml file

```
 android:background ="#88676767" or "#88000000"
```

**Option 2.** 
On your image view or any other view

```
view.setColorFilter(Color.argb(150, 155, 155, 155),   Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

**Option 3:**
On your layout

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.test_layout);
Drawable dd = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.test);
dd.setAlpha(50);
ll.setBackgroundDrawable(dd);
```

It might be helpful for you.